# digitalRead and digitalWrite are too slow in Arduino when using BLENano

Tags: c++, assembly, arduino, i2c

I'm trying to speed up the digitalRead and digitalWrite calls in Arduino, I am using the RedBearLabs BLENano. I was able to cut my overall routine time down from 5.5ms to 1.6ms, but ultimately I cannot speed it up anymore without going deeper on the digitalRead and digitalWrite calls. Is there a way to do the write the read in direct assembly? Here is my routine, which is called 32,000 times to read 4000 bytes of data over I2C:

```
bool I2C_ReadBit() {
  bool b;

  digitalWrite(SCL,HIGH);

  int pSDA = digitalRead(SDA);  
  b = (pSDA == HIGH) ? 1 : 0;

  digitalWrite(SCL,LOW);

  return b;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to optimize? Note that your code could be slightly better if you dropped the ternary ? 1 : 0 on an already boolean value.

Comment: If this was a regular AVR-based Arduino it would be straightforward to step down to direct port manipulation - no need for assembly as you can get avr-gcc / -g++ to generate single instruction cod for setting and clearing a specified bit in a given port register. It should be possible to do something similar with the processor on your board. Of course, many of the AVR have dedicated I2C hardware so you wouldn't need to bit-bang at all.

Comment: Isn't the I2C some sort of serial bus in it's nature, so reading/writing bits over it has certain speed limits? And if those bits are incoming trough BLE, it has it's own maximum speed to receive data. 4000B in 1.6ms is 2441.4 kiB/s. Which is out of grasp already for some worse I2C implementations (down to ~100k or 400k bit/s, while you are already around 10Mibit/s). So just make sure you understand the full path of your data from the origin, all the speed limits involved, and calculate the theoretical maximum throughput. Maybe you are already close to it... or still 100x slower).

Comment: Oh, I messed up bits/bytes of your code, so the speed I calculated is completely off. But I hope you will get the idea.

Comment: Unrelated to your performance issue, but if you're conforming to I2C, you can't read a bit off the bus until you see that your SCL pin is high after the master has released it. This is because the slave may be holding SCL low while it is busy.

Comment: This is the master and that is why we are also modifying the CLK, which is a main reason it is so slow. The slave is quite fast at sending the data, the main issue is the slave has to wait for the CLK to send the next bit. I did track the timing down to the digitalRead/digitalWrites being the bottle neck.

Comment: digitalWrite and digitalRead are indeed incredibly slow. you can go into the source files and get just the code you need to do it directly, with the registers that correspond to your SCL/SDA ports. you have to do some digging but you'll get down to the assembler instructions in the end. ping me if you can't find it.